# Forcing method sequences on ActionScript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, sequence, synchronous

I'm having problems with asynchronous sequences on Flex/ActionScript.
Here is an example:

```
private function start():void{
    _menu = new MyMenu();
    _screen.addElement(_menu);
    //Here, some Mouse Event Listener to Menu Click
}
```

Now, let's assume that a click on the menu happened.

```
private function menuClick(event:Event):void{
    removeMenu();
    addMenu(event.SomethingPassedByTheClick);
}
```

Now, forget about the error on the event handler thing, let's just think about the process, ok?
My problem is that sometimes addMenu() finishes before removeMenu(), which leads to errors.
The above script is just a logical representation of my problem, not a real script. To sunup, I need to be able to define that the method addMenu() HAS to wait for removeMenu() to be done before be called. Any thoughts?
Thanks for your attention.

Edit:

A more accurate example of my problem:

```
private function createComplete():void{
       _screenArray = new Array(
                new Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                new Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                new Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0));
       startUp();
}

private function startUp():void{
    //Some mathematical calculations that changes a few 0 to 1's.
    addNewComponent();
}

private function addNewComponent():void{
    removeAllComponents();
    //More calculus on the array in order to create a component in vague space.
    addComponentOnCalculatedArea(x, y);
    //here is my problem: Sometimes, add Method is called before the removeAllComponents, which causes the new added component be removed by the removeAllComponents() method.
}
```

Thanks everyone. I had the wrong premise. What was wrong whas my mathematics calcs, not the order of the methods being called. I noticed that by adding trace() in each method of the Script.

Comment: Can you post an independent sample application maybe? I'm not sure I totally follow here because there's no way something could interject in the middle there. As a thought experiment put an infinite while loop after removAllComponents and notice that nothing gets executed

Comment: Unless your `removeAllComponents` method executes in an asynchronous manner then the `addComponentOnCalculatedArea` cannot be fired until `removeAllComponents` has completed execution.  You should deploy some traces or step though with a debugger to see what's really going on.

Comment: We would need to see the code in `removeAllComponents()` and `addNewComponent()` to figure out what is wrong.  Also, maybe `addComponentOnCalculatedArea()`.

Comment: I'd really love to know how you're creating asynchronous actionscript code, since there is no such thing (spare the case of pixel bender filters, which require a callback and the VM handles joining the thread back to the main actionscript thread anyway). Actionscript is 100% always executed in the same thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should hinge on the component lifecycle to know when things are available. Don't add the mouse event until the creationComplete event of the menu object is fired.

You will run into a lot of asynchronous issues if you don't hinge on the events.  This is the basis of asynchronous applications!

On top of that you should set flags when things are accomplished. If it is critical to never allow removeMenu to be evaluated before addMenu is finished you should be doing something like this:

```
private function start():void{
    _menu = new MyMenu();
    _menu.addEventListener(FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE, eventHandler);
    _screen.addElement(_menu);
}

private function eventHandler(...rest):void{
    _menuCreated = true;
    _menu.removeEventListener(FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE, eventHandler);
}

private function menuClick(event:Event):void{
    if(!_menuCreated){
        return;
    }

    removeMenu();
    addMenu(event.SomethingPassedByTheClick);
}
```

Something along those lines.

Also you mentioned something about AddMenu waiting for RemoveMenu. While as3 is asynchronous it is also single threaded. You won't have multiple functions evaluating at the same time. When RemoveMenus is running AddMenu won't.

To make this clearer lets supposed we do this:

```
    private function doFirst():void{
        trace("first");
    }

    private function doSecond():void{
        trace("second");
    }

    private function doThings():void{
        doFirst();
        doSecond();
    }
```

In this example it will ALWAYS print "first" then "second" if you call `doThings` no matter how long `doFirst` takes. If `doFirst` has an infinite while loop nothing will break its flow control, it will stall the entire application.

Now if `doFirst()` dispatches some events and needs to do things asynchornously then the things it dispatches can happen after `doSecond` but not the finishing of the `doFirst` function.  If thats the case you should register an event listener for `doSecond` to fire after all the work in `doFirst` is completed.

Like I also mentioned, you  can set flags in the event handlers of the work you need to do and then you can invalidate the properties of your components. This will call `commitProperties` and you can do the next items there.

Check http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=ascomponents_advanced_3.html and http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html#commitProperties() which are links explaining the asynchronous lifecycle of components and how to deal with setting properties asynchronously.

Comment: That is not exactly the case as it is impossible to generate a click if the Menu was not created yet. My problem comes after the first menu was already created. When I remove the first one and want to create the second one, I want it to be sequential as remove first, after that add another one.
About the single-thread, I know that. But for asynchronous reason, sometimes the addMenu() runs before the removeMenus().

Comment: How are you removing the menu? Are you removing it from the parent components children list explicity? Is this a popup?  Some more sample code would help me give a better answer

Comment: In your code addMenu will wait for removeMenu to finish unless you make removeMenu asynchronous by removing things with other events. In which case you should hinge addMenu to listen to all your finished events and synchronize that way.

Comment: Actually, is not a screen manager at all, but I thought it would be easier to explain. I have an 'global' bi-dimensional array that maps a lot of bits. Some events require more than 1 method to work on the said array. But in those cases, I need one method to work on the mapping first and only after it finishes, the other one starts to work with the array that was resulted from the first handler.

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu In that case you can listen for [Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#ADDED_TO_STAGE) and [Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#REMOVED_FROM_STAGE) to find out when a menu was added or removed. But I have to say that you are doing things manually, which the Flex framework takes care of automatically.

Comment: Like I mentioned, flex is single threaded. Nothing is working on anything simultaneously.  If you start one method to work on your global array then the second method won't start till the first finishes.

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu I didn't read that last comment: that's a totally different question. This can be handled synchronously, unless I'm not understanding the problem well.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with devshorts' answer, but in the final function I would add a callback as well:

```
private function menuClick(event:Event):void{
    if(!_menuCreated){
        return;
    }
    removeMenu.addlistener(someCompleteEvent, menuRemoved);  // Don't add until you are sure.
}

private function menuRemoved (SomethingPassedByTheClick: ClickEvent): void{
    addMenu(event.SomethingPassedByTheClick);
}
```

This would help to verify that the menu removal was complete prior to adding the new menu.